# Can I use Cygwin to compile C/C++ code with Momentics?

Tags: c++, qnx, momentics

I'm playing around with QNX's IDE Momentics. I'm currently making local C/C++ code. When I try to run a file, I choose "local C/C++ application", and it then gives me a choice of configurations. My question is if I can use the GCC compiler from Cygwin in Momentics to build my programs, and anyone knows HOW to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After not getting an answer (thanks stack community) and working on it I've figured it out.
1) Since the Cygwin GCC compiler is on the PATH, Momentics automatically sees it and will use it. No need for explicit selection.
2) Momentics can't compile and run code to be executed locally, it only works for targeted remote execution. So I can compile and run my program on a VM, but not on my host machine.